# jpackage Greek Language EULA not readable

Tags: java, deployment, jpackage

I have successfully generated an installable package with `jpackage`. All seems to work as expected.

My problem is that the Greek characters from my `License.txt` file are not readable as you can see in the picture below.

[image: japackage Eula screenshot]

I don't know if it is relevant but I will mention that:

1. When the package is created from CMD I add `--java-options -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` but this made no difference.
2. Also, my Java application can read-write Greek characters from files, database and from http-restful.
3. I tried to add a License.html file with HTML code inside with no success [image: html file]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: share with us the complete CMD command that you execute please

Comment: 'jpackage --input app -n Name --app-version 1.0.0 --description "mia mikri perigrafi" --copyright "Copyright 2022, All rights reserved" --vendor "Vendor" --license-file app\License.txt --main-jar Name.jar --main-class com.name.name.name --type exe --install-dir Dir/name --win-shortcut --win-dir-chooser --win-menu --win-menu-group "Menu Group" --icon app\gland.ico --java-options '--enable-preview' --java-options -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true --java-options -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies on the character encoding of your txt file. Open it with Notepad++ (or a decent txt editor) and check if your file is correctly set to UTF-8.
[image]

Comment: I tried this but with no luck! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you.
Your license file format should be RTF - license.rtf.
It is WiX requirement.
If you look at config/ui.wxf, you'll find WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf"